# Положение консольного окна на экране

Tags: java, консоль, позиционирование

Есть несколько консольных Java приложений. Запуск приложений производится через `*.bat` файлы на которые сделаны ярлыки. Окна открываются в случайном месте на экране, что требует постоянно их раздвигать.

Вопрос: возможно ли задать позицию консольного окна в параметрах запуска или изменить его положение после старта приложения?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом bat-файле вряд ли, но можно задать положение консоли по умолчанию. Это в свойствах в закладке Расположение снять опцию «Автоматический выбор» и указать значения левого и верхнего края.

Comment: Спасибо. Я думал, что это повлияет на все окна сразу. Ан нет. Ошибался.